# Where is the "System.Composition.TypedParts.dll"?

Tags: mef

I am trying to use the **ContainerConfiguration** type from the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF). According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.composition.hosting.containerconfiguration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it lives in "**System.Composition.TypedParts.dll**" which is part of .NET Framework 4.5. But I cannot find it in Add Reference for a .NET 4.5 application.

[image]

Where can I find this DLL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out to be part of MEF 2, which needs to be installed with NuGet. It's not distributed with .NET Framework.

Comment: in nuget run `Install-Package Microsoft.Composition`