# How to access complete solution using Roslyn?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I am trying to access a complete project solution from a console application in Roslyn. I was referring to [this walkthrough](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/). I have installed all the corresponding build tools mentioned.

This is my code :

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string solutionPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.sln";
            var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(); //This line throws the exception
            var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Composition.TypedParts, Version=1.0.27.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I should update the installation instructions on there. Did you install the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis stuff via NuGet? Is there a reference to System.Composition.TypedParts.dll in your project? If not, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658599/where-is-the-system-composition-typedparts-dll